# How to get data from second generated key in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to be able to obtain the data that is marked in yellow and then show it in a recyclerView of Android, but I do not know how to obtain the Key that is generated randomly with the push () that is marked in red.

[image: Reference image with colors]

I've seen various videos, tutorials, and documentation, but what I've accomplished the most is displaying the data marked in green.

I am attaching code with which I have shown what is marked in green (I want to be able to show the data in yellow)

```
public class mostrarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerPa;
DatabaseReference database;
Adapter adapter;
ArrayList<Pacientes> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar);

    recyclerPa = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerPa);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usuarios");
    recyclerPa.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerPa.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new Adapter(this,list);
    recyclerPa.setAdapter(adapter);

    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                Pacientes pacientes = dataSnapshot.getValue(Pacientes.class);
                list.add(pacientes);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data you want to show is nested under two levels of dynamic keys, you will need to two nested loops over `getChildren()`.

```
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
            for (DataSnapshot patientSnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()){ //  add an extra loop
                if (patientSnapshot.hasChild("nombre")) { //  check for object
                    Pacientes pacientes = patientSnapshot.getValue(Pacientes.class);
                    if (pacientes != null) { //  skip non-patient nodes (see note below)
                        list.add(pacientes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); //  Never ignore errors
    }
});
```

---

In general your data structure violates Firebase's recommendation of [not building nested data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data), so I recommend studying the documentation on [structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data) and watching David's excellent video series on [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had tried using another for, but as with the one you put, it gives me the same error "PID: 2719
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.psicoapp.Pacientes".

and again thanks for all the explanation, it really helps me a lot, I already want to learn about Firebase, I will see all the information and videos that you put me, but a separate query, is it better to use Firestore? then I intend to host in "Pacientes" some url of photos that the user uploads from the app

Comment: I added one more check to see if we can prevent that error, which btw also comes from the data structure problem I explained at the end of my answer. Firestore and Realtime Database both have their use-cases. To help you decide, have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore